# Spline regression for binary dependent variables

Tags: logistic, splines

I am trying to analyze the relationship between a discrete quantitative independent variable and a binary qualitative dependent variable.

My hypothesis is that higher levels of the predictor promotes the response to be positive. However, lower levels of the predictor do not promote the response to be negative. Thus, I expect the positive outcome when the predictor is high, but I also expect it sometimes when the predictor is low.

This is an example of my dataset:

```
response  predictor
   -          0
   +          0
   +          20
   +          26
   -          1
   +          3
   -          0
   +          19
```

This is the reason which makes me think about spline regression. However, I don't find how to apply it when the response variable is binary.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: One way is via a generalized additive model using the binomial distribution as the conditional distribution of the response and a logit link. This would give a logistic regression model but with a smooth effect of your predictor (on the scale of the link function) instead of a linear effect of the predictor (on the scale of the link function).

Comment: Check this link, gives an example on how to fit you want using R and gam package. Check Logistic Regression GAMs. http://www.science.smith.edu/~jcrouser/SDS293/labs/lab13-r.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spline regression in X for binary Y has been used extensively since 1984.  Detailed case studies with R code may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/rms).  Regression splines are useful for all types of regression models, and work the same for binary, ordinal, continuous, categorical, and censored Y.